# Can't apply jquery function on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emojione

I am using emoji library called [EmojiOne](http://emojione.com) , I am using the following code from one of their example to convert text to emojis, it works fine when I load the page but when a new element appears dynamically it doesn't work on them until I refresh the page. How can I get it to work on dynamically loaded ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".convert-emoji").each(function() {
        var original = $(this).html();
        var converted = emojione.toImage(original);
        $(this).html(converted);
    });
});
```

Here is the link to the example: http://git.emojione.com/demos/class-convert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doThing();
});

function doThing(){
    $(".convert-emoji").each(function() {
            var original = $(this).html();
            var converted = emojione.toImage(original);
            $(this).html(converted);
    });
}

function yourAppendFunction(){
    //here are you appending new element and the fire the function

    doThing();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract this code to a function and call this function where you want... Or set up an interval...

```
function refreshEmojis() {
    $(".convert-emoji").each(function() {
        var original = $(this).html();
        var converted = emojione.toImage(original);
        $(this).html(converted);
    });
}

$(document).ready(refreshEmojis); //on page load

$("#someButtonId").on("click", function() { //click of some button
    //some action...
    refreshEmojis();
});

setInterval(refreshEmojis, 100); //each 100 milliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! It somewhat works, when I posted first message ":)" it stayed like that, but when I posted the 2nd message ":)" first messaged change to a emoji but the 2nd remained as plain text.

Comment: any idea on how I can get it to work on new message as well ?

Comment: you must have an async ajax call and you are putting the code after the call... you must put refreshEmojis() call in the ajax callback... put your postMessage code in the question, let me see that